# iPhone JSON Retreving Value

Tags: iphone, json

Hi
I am passing one api and getting the response from the server

```
[{\"Latitude\":\"34\",\"Longitude\":\"45\"},{\"Latitude\":\"46\",\"Longitude\":\"45\"},{\"Latitude\":\"73\",\"Longitude\":\"54\"}]
```

however i didn't know how to break the response which i have got from server into array, so that i can store the values and used it..

Answer (score 1):

It's standard JSON. Lots of libraries out there that do exactly that. I would recommend SBJSON.

http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/

Answer (score 0):

to expend on MarPowell answer - this is JSON check out the JSON website - http://www.json.org/

also if you wants to parse it in iPhone sdk check out this great tutorial - http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-json-twitter-api/

Comment: hey saurabh thanks, only thing i wanted to do is information which is coming from service into nsarray from, have to break into two strings, one for latitude and one for longitude only